# Pub/Sub Cloud Function does not Update Document in Subcollection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update a field in my document in Firestore. The general location of the document would be "/games/{userId}/userGames/{gameId}. And in this game, there is a property called "status" which changes accordingly to the games start and end time.

As you can guess, the if the start time is bigger than the "now" timestamp and the status is "*TO_BE_PLAYED*", the game will begin and the status will be 1, "*BEING_PLAYED*". Also, if the end time is bigger than the "now" timestamp and the status is "*BEING_PLAYED*", the game will end, therefore the status will be 2, "*PLAYED*". I want to create a cloud function that is capable to do so.

However, even if the function logs output 'ok', the values are never updated. Unfortunately, I do not have that much experience in Javascript too.

**THE CODE**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const STATUS_PLAYED = 2;
const STATUS_BEING_PLAYED = 1;
const STATUS_TO_BE_PLAYED = 0;

exports.handleBeingPlayedGames = functions.runWith({memory: "2GB"}).pubsub.schedule('* * * * *')
     .timeZone('Europe/Istanbul') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
     .onRun(async () => {
       // current time & stable
                            // was Timestamp.now();
       const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate( new Date());

       const querySnapshot = await db.collection("games").get();
       const promises = [];

       querySnapshot.forEach( doc => {
           const docRef = doc.ref;
           console.log(docRef);
           promises.push(docRef.collection("userGames").where("status", "==", STATUS_BEING_PLAYED).where("endtime", "<", now).get());
       });
       const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);

       const promises1 = [];

       snapshotArrays.forEach( snapArray => {
           snapArray.forEach(snap => {
               promises1.push(snap.ref.update({
                   "status": STATUS_PLAYED,
               }));
           });
       });

       return Promise.all(promises1);

   });

exports.handleToBePlayedGames = functions.runWith({memory: "2GB"}).pubsub.schedule('* * * * *')
     .onRun(async () => {
       // current time & stable

                            // was Timestamp.now();
       const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());

       const querySnapshot = await db.collection("games").get();
       const promises = [];

       querySnapshot.forEach( async doc => {
           const docData = await doc.ref.collection("userGames").where("status", "==", STATUS_TO_BE_PLAYED).where("startTime", ">", now).get();
           promises.push(docData);
       });
       const snapshotArrays = await Promise.all(promises);

       const promises1 = [];

       snapshotArrays.forEach( snapArray => {
           snapArray.forEach(snap => {
               promises1.push(snap.ref.update({
                   "status": STATUS_BEING_PLAYED,
               }));
           });
       });

       return Promise.all(promises1);

   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this answer goes to lurkers trying to solve this problem.

First I tried to solve this problem by brute force and not including much thinking and tried to acquire the value in subcollection. However, as I searched, I've found that denormalizing (flattening) data actually solves the problem a bit.

I created a new directory under `/status/{gameId}` with the properties
`endTime, startTime, and status field` and I actually did it on a single level by using promises. Sometimes denormalizing data can be your savior.

Comment: Hey, remember to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) after 48h have gone by since the post's creation.

Answer (score 0):

How can `startTime` be greater than `now`? Is it set by default to a date in the future?

My current assumption is that a game cannot set it's status to `STATUS_BEING_PLAYED` because of the inconsistency with `startTime`. Moreover, a game cannot have the status `STATUS_PLAYED` because it depends on having `STATUS_BEING_PLAYED`, which cannot have.

My recommendation would be to set the field `startTime` and `endTime` to `null` by default. If you do so you can check if a game has to be set to `STATUS_BEING_PLAYED` with this:

```
doc.ref.collection("userGames")
  .where("status", "==", STATUS_TO_BE_PLAYED)
  .where("startTime", "<", now)
  .where("endTime", "==", null)
  .get();
```

You could check if a game has to be on `STATUS_PLAYED` with this (exactly as you did):

```
docRef.collection("userGames")
  .where("status", "==", STATUS_BEING_PLAYED)
  .where("endtime", "<", now)
  .get();
```

Now there's something that you should wonder, is this the best approach to change a game's status? You are querying the whole game library of a user **every single minute** as you know [read operations are charged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations) so this approach would imply meaningful charges. Maybe you should simply use update the game's status when the game is started and closed.

Also notice that the equals operation is `==`, not `=`.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. The startTime and endTime properties are set via user in the app and therefore they are not null. And as they create the game after the current date as I limited so, the status property will be TO_BE_PLAYED initially. Regarding your previous question, how can I know when the game has started if I do not run a backend function? Any recommendation is heavily appreciated.

Comment: I think I'm lacking many context in this situation. I assumed it was a game library such as Steam, but now I realize that it may be something like booking football games. Sorry for my misunderstanding. What you should do first is use `==` instead of `=`. After that check what your `get` queries return. Try to remove `where` conditions in order to find which one is causing you the lack of results.

Comment: Also I think there's something redundant with the `await` statements. The code waits for the `games` retrieval, then waits for each `userGames` and waits again with `Promise.all`. I think that all of this is redundant and could be handled with a single [collectionGroup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query `await db.collectionGroup('userGames').where(...).get()`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help man, I have added an answer for my solution.